# Django image src not found

Tags: python, django

```
\project_structure
-app
\project
  -settings.py
  -...
\picture
  -panda.jpg
```

I've uploaded the picture into `picture`.

```
class Goods(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='picture')
```

And the data in `database` is **picture/panda.jpg**

Now,how can i show it in html?

I wrote this in html:

```
<p>{{each.pic}}</p>
<img src='{{ each.pic.url }}' />
```

And the source codes in browser is this:

```
picture/panda.jpg
<img src='picture/panda.jpg' />
```

The image was linked to **http://localhost:8000/my_sell/picture/panda.jpg**.And couldn't show.

How can i solve this,I've tried add `media_root` in `settings.py` and useless.

Comment: `media_root` should be uppercase (`MEDIA_ROOT`). Check if it works by changing it.

Comment: can you provide your URL file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did not check this but almost all code are taken from my working projects :).

`settings.py`:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
)
```

`models`:

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings


image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
    # Physical file location ROOT
    location=u'{0}/my_sell/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
    # Url for file
    base_url=u'{0}my_sell/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
)


def image_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/my_sell/picture/<filename>
    return u'picture/{0}'.format(filename)


class Goods(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage)
```

`views`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def view_picture(request):
    c = dict()
    c['goods'] = Goods.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', c)
```

`templates`:

```html
{% for product in goods %} 
    {% if product.pic %}    
        <img src="{{ product.pic.url }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Edited**: Don't forget to add MEDIA_URL into root `urls.py`

```py
if settings.DEBUG
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hi.I've updated my codes.And the picture is stored at **/project/media/my_sell/picture/panda.jpg**.But the image still can't show.URL:`<img src="/media/my_sell/picture/panda.jpg">`